# Direct List assignment in python - not inserting

Tags: python, algorithm, list, insert

I am trying to code a function in python which takes a list x, takes a zero based index n and another value num and then assigns that value at that position:

I figured this morning that we can't do a direct assignment like we can in the case of an array in some other programming languages like

```
x=[] //an empty array
x[0]="some  value"
```

So i searched for an alternative and found the insert function for lists which takes 2 arguments and insert values at the specified position like

```
>>> x=[0]
>>> x.insert(123,"as")
>>> x
[0, 'as']
>>> x[0]
0
>>> x[1]
'as'
>>> x.insert(0,1)
>>> x
[1, 0, 'as']
>>> len(x)
3
>>> x.insert(4,"dfsdf")
>>> x
[1, 0, 'as', 'dfsdf']
>>> x.insert(4,"dfsdf")
>>> x
[1, 0, 'as', 'dfsdf', 'dfsdf']
```

The problem with this function is that if that element is already present in the list, it creates a duplicate - something that does not happen with

```
x[0]="some -value" 

//if the value is not present it appends the value otherwise it overwrites the value at x[0]
```

So I wrote another function insertAt which will check for a given list- if the value is already present at that position n- if not it will insert otherwise it will return the same list. Here it goes:

```
def insertAt(x,n,num):
  if n>=len(x): 
    return x.insert(len(x),num)
  elif n<len(x) and x[n] != num:
    return x.insert(n,num)
  else:
    return x
```

It's pretty self explanatory- except that it always returns me None - why is it not returning a valid value??

Comment: ``return x`` instead of ``x.insert(len(x),num)`` and ``x.insert(n,num)`` after insertion.

Comment: Why are you using `return` when working with lists? You're editing the original list in this case, you don't need to return it.

Comment: right, i got it. return will work on the original list.

Comment: I'm going to make a copy of the list and then use that thanks.!!

Comment: You don't need to make a copy. Your modification will reflect in the original list.

Comment: I'm interested. Which programming languages let you assign to an empty array?

Comment: @Prabhas, DON'T make a copy of the list!

Comment: `x.insert(nm num)` does not return anything, it modifies the list itself. So you need first to insert the element and then return the list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to return the modified list.

```
def insertAt(x,n,num):
  if n>=len(x): 
    x.insert(len(x),num)
    return x
  elif n<len(x) and x[n] != num:
    x.insert(n,num)
    return x
  else:
    return x
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a copy of the list why you don't try this?

```
def insertAt(l, n, num):
    if len(l)<n or l[n] != num:
       return l[:n]+[num]+l[n:]
    return l
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x=[] //an empty array
x[0]="some  value"
```

won't work. Here, no memory is allocated at first statement. And then you are trying to assign something to unallocated memory. How is it possible? If you define the list like,

```
x = [0]*10
```

and then try to assign directly, it will work.
`x[2] = 2`

This should work. In your case, if you want to store string as a list of characters, you can do something like this,

```
x = list("some value")
print x //['s', 'o', 'm', 'e', ' ', 'v', 'a', 'l', 'u', 'e']
```